# Why wont my random image generator show?

Tags: javascript, html

My random images wont display. I even ran it through a html validator and still cant seem to find the error.

```
function showImg() {
        /*
            The showImg() function displays a random image from the 0.png through 9.png files. The random image is designed to thwart hackers attemting to enter the library records database by requiring visual confirmation.

        */

        var imgNumber = randomInteger(9):// Return a random number from 0 to 9
        document.write ("<img src='" + imgNumber + ".png' alt=' ' />");
        }




      </script>



<script type="text/javascript">
                    showImg();
                    showImg();
                    showImg();
                    showImg();
                    showImg();
                </script>
```

Comment: What is purpose of using `document.write()`? Can you include `html` at Question? Quotes at `"<img src='" + imgNumber + ".png' alt=' ' />"` do not appear to match?

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? What's the `randomInteger` function? Also, you have a typo in `var imgNumber = randomInteger(9):` (the colon at the end)

Comment: are you sure randomInteger returns 4 not 4.0 ? can you please add the implementation of it ?

Comment: Won't work how? Are there any errors you have in the console? Is `randomInteger` even working? What happened when you stepped through it using a debugger?

Comment: I didnt get any errors in console...Im doing this work based off of a text book, and it works in the book...

Comment: if you replace [ " + imgNumber + " ] with a number, does it show an image?

Comment: @nocturn2 no it doesnt.

Comment: Ok , it works for  me now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust `showImg` to

```
function showImg() { 
  var imgNumber = randomInteger(9);// Return a random number from 0 to 9 
  document.body.innerHTML += "<img src=" + imgNumber + ".png alt='' />"; 
}
```

for `randomInteger` function you can use

```
function randomInteger(n) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - 0 + 1)) + 0
}
```

See also [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/VTaRXAsXoAiwVTiy7yh7?p=preview

Comment: oh gods...now I saw the mistake. Why didn't you just say "you have `:` instead of `;`"?

Comment: @vlaz There were other syntax errors at Question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680573/why-wont-my-random-image-generator-show/39680704?noredirect=1#comment66661442_39680573. User j08691 mentioned that error at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680573/why-wont-my-random-image-generator-show/39680704?noredirect=1#comment66661472_39680573

Comment: @phillipswag _"that still doesnt make the image show :("_ What do you mean? Are the images in the same directory as `.html` document?

Comment: @guest271314 Ok it works, but it displays the same image instead of random images like I want it too.

Comment: @phillipswag _"Ok it works, but it displays the same image instead of random images like I want it too."_ Do you mean that the same random number is possibly selected again?

Comment: With this solution you'll also have to have an image 0.pgn, but it worked for me.

Comment: @nocturns2 See original Question at _"`// Return a random number from 0 to 9`"_

Comment: what do you mean? @nocturns92

Comment: It was something I overlooked, and just thinking 9 images instead of 10 with 0 base.

Comment: @nocturns2 0-9 is a total of 10 possible options

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are your images stored in the same folder as the page you're calling ? If they are in a subfolder then you obviously need to specify the path in your code - either relative or absolute.

Comment: Yup, they are in the same folder.

Comment: Nvm it works now, i tried in a different broswer. Now i just need to figure out how to get my images to be random.